# How can I root my galaxy S3 i9300 on android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean?

Tags: rooting, updates, samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.2-jelly-bean

I want to update my S3 the latest jelly bean. Please provide me an **easy-to-follow step by step** tutorial on rooting my S3 i9300.